# 'dict' object has not attribute 'pk' when using Django bulk_update()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, bulkupdate

I have the following code:

```
obj = Products.objects.filter(dump__product_name = 'ABC, dump__product_color = 'black').values()
new_price = [100, 200, 300]

for item in range(len(obj)):
   obj[item]['price'] -= new_price[item]

Products.objects.filter(dump__product_name = 'ABC, dump__product_color = 'black').bulk_update(obj, ['price'])
```

But I am getting the error, `Exception inside application: 'dict' has no attribute 'pk'`

The value of obj looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'product_name': 'Acer - Laptop', 'price': 350}, 
           {'id': 1, 'product_name': 'Dell - Laptop', 'price': 450}, 
           {'id': 1, 'product_name': 'Samsung- Laptop', 'price': 650}]>
```

I am unable to figure out what's wrong with the code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This is one of the *many* resons, *not* to use `.values()`.

Comment: See for example https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Answer (score 1):

The `QuerySet.values` method returns a sequence of dicts, but `QuerySet.bulk_update` takes a sequence of model instances, not dicts. You should iterate over the `QuerySet` returned by the `filter` method for a sequence of model instances that you can make changes to instead, and you also don't have to filter again when you perform `bulk_update` because it's performed on instances of specific primary keys:

```
items = list(Products.objects.filter(dump__product_name='ABC', dump__product_color='black'))
new_prices = [100, 200, 300]

for item, new_price in zip(items, new_prices):
   item.price -= new_price

Products.objects.bulk_update(items, ['price'])
```

Comment: There is pretty much only one good way to do this after all. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.values()` since that will create dictionaries instead of model objects, and thus does not offer all the functionality the model provides.

You can work with:

```
obj = list(Products.objects.filter(
    dump__product_name = 'ABC', dump__product_color = 'black'
))
new_price = [100, 200, 300]

for item, prc in zip(obj, new_price):
   item.price -= prc

Products.objects.bulk_update(obj, ['price'])
```